# Are all binaries executable in x86 architecture?

Tags: operating-system, x86, executable, embedded-linux

I went through the following statement in a book.

> the executable target binaries from an embedded distribution will not run on your PC, but are targeted to the architecture and processor of your embedded system. (Of course, if your embedded Linux distribution targets the x86 architecture, this statement does not apply.)

Are all binaries executable in x86 architecture?
Can someone brief?

Comment: Your title (and question) is/are not a proper rewording of the quoted text.  The literal answer is "no", all binaries are not executable.  Binary files are simply the opposite of text files.  A data file of hex values would not consist of text nor executable code.  The quotation is about **executable** binaries. When talking about code files, there are source, object and binary files.  In that context binary files would refer to executable files (for the appropriate architecture/processor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement means that *if you cross-compile a program to an embedded platform* you can't run it on your desktop system that has an x86 CPU, *unless* the target platform happens to be x86 also. It doesn't imply that an x86 CPU understands ARM instructions for example.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thank you Joni for clarifying.